# Twisted centralizer

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $F$ denote a finite field and $A$ a square matrix with coefficients in $F$. The set of all matrices $B$ such that $BA=AB$ is called the centraliser of $A$.

Now consider the set $C(a,A)$ of all matrices $B$ satisfying $AB=aBA$ where $a$ is in $F$. We call this set the twisted centraliser of $A$. It is an $F$-vector space. Are there bounds in the linear algebra literature on its dimension?

Comment: Do you have *any* reference for such twisted centralizer of square matrices? I can't find anything in the web.

Comment: Sorry I have not seen this definition anywhere. I made up the name!

Comment: After searching I found the name mentioned in https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v58/yu4474.pdf but am unsure about the definition..

Comment: This is a bit tricky unless the minimal polynomial of $A$ happens to be irreducible over $F$ in which case it becomes trivial and the answer is zero.